# Meaningful auto-generated name for PID for debug purposes?

Tags: erlang, elixir

There's some process started with `Task.Supervisor.start_child`, if something went wrong Elixir (Erlang) prints error message like this:

```
23:56:06.257 [error] Task #PID<0.216.0> started from #PID<0.137.0> terminating
```

It's hard to understand what process crashed. I wonder if there's a way to give a meaningful **auto-generated** names to processes? So the error will be more descriptive, like:

```
23:56:06.257 [error] Task #PID-REQUEST-HANDLER<0.216.0> started from #PID-SOCKET-LOOP<0.137.0> terminating
```

Comment: I think this is more of an Erlang question. I know you're using Elixir but those messages are coming from the BEAM and that's squarely in the realm of Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

You can name each desired process with `register/2` function:

Erlang:

```
register(RegName, PidOrPort) -> true
```

Elixir:

```
register(pid | port, atom) :: true
```

Then what you need is implementing your logger to use `process_info(PID, registered_name)` function to get the registered name of the desired process by its PID and formatting the log text with that name.

**Update:** Also it is good to know that [`error_logger`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html) is an event manager ([gen_event](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_event.html)). Error, warning, crash, progress and info events are sent to the error logger from the Erlang runtime system and the different Erlang/OTP applications. It has some default event handlers, as well as [`sasl`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sasl_app.html) which is an OTP application that adds more logging features to your application. You can also write your own event handler and add it to `error_logger` event manager.

Comment: Thanks. Can it cause memory leak, as far as I know you can't auto-generate atoms? Something like `register(pid, 'req-handler-' + some-autoincremented-counter)`

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin For debugging purposes it can be an option but it's not a good practice in production when it comes to register a lot of processes because the atom table is not garbage-collected. Also in case of auto generating atoms you can generate a string and convert it to an atom with `list_to_atom/1` function.